# Search a value on a table between ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, lookup

My goal is to write a formula that would return a value from a table if it fall under 2 specific ranges.

[image]
According to data on column B (X values) and C (Y values), column D (Z values) would be filled if X and Y fall under a range in table from H6 to M8.

Comment: When Y has a value 1, does it take the Z value from the first or second column?  Same if it has a value of 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott's answer above is the better solution if you can rearrange your data.  However if you cannot, and also to demonstrate some other formula's you could use the following in cell D4 and copy down:

```
=VLOOKUP(B4,$F$6:$M$8,IF(AND(C4>=$H$5,C4<$I$5),3,IF(AND(C4>=$J$5,C4<$K$5),5,IF(AND(C4>=$L$5,C4<$M$5),7,"ERROR out of table"))),1)
```

Formula's used:

- VLOOKUP
- IF
- AND

Drawbacks of this method:  You need to add each of your column range checks for your Y value in IF statements.  They will get long and there is a limit to how far you can nest IF statements.  It will make for difficult debugging and editing if you ever needed to add a column.  VLOOKUP requires the search column in the lookup table to be on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Change your lookup range to just the From numbers:

[image]

Then use this formula:

```
=INDEX($G$5:$I$7,MATCH(B4,$F$5:$F$7),MATCH(C4,$G$4:$I$4))
```

[image]

Comment: I will be AFK for the rest of the day, so have at it. 8P @ForwardEd

Comment: Many thanks for this. It works very good. Now I have another problem, my array in the index formula has some blank cells. Is there a formula that I can use to fill those blank cells interpolating data from the surrounding cells?

Comment: maybe.  best to ask as anther question and reference this question if need be.